# RabbitMQ: erl.exe taking high CPU usages

Tags: c#, performance, rabbitmq, erl

I have implemented rabbitmq in my application and it's running on windows server 2008 server, the problem is that erl.exe taking high CPU usages like sometime it reaches 40-45% CPU usages, even in the ideal case (when not processing any queue) it takes at least 4-15% CPU usages.

What could be the reason for taking high CPU usages? Is there any setting or any other thing that I need to do.

Comment: What's on the server logs?

Comment: @old_sound Nothing about erl.

Comment: I mean, on the RabbitMQ logs

Comment: @old_sound Nothing written in rabbitmq log

Comment: Is anyone listening to the queue at the moment? If so what? You've tagged the question as C#, so I assume that more than likely you are using EasyNetQ? Can you show how you are subscribing to the servicebus? What are the specifications of the Windows 2008 server?

Comment: Maybe is related to this old bug when the windows return from sleep mode or hibernate:
http://markmail.org/thread/zlksjp24hifef5qk

Answer (score 2):

You say that even when not processing a queue it is still at 4-15%, but is your application running? If you weren't before, try to monitor erl while no application is using Rabbit.

One thing that comes to mind is that you might be using the `QueingBasicConsumer` in a loop and that could be contributing to the CPU usage.   If you are using `QueingBasicConsumer` and it is what is causing the hit, try substituting it with `EventingBasicConsumer` (such that you don't do busy waiting) and see if you have improvement.

Also, how is your application using Rabbit? According to the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) every IConnection is backed up by a background thread and if you're creating a bunch of connections in your application it could be another reason for the slow down.